# github-linguist including files with linguist-vendored attribute in language statistics

Tags: git, github-linguist

I have a github repository that is predominately C++ but has lots of vendor-generated C code (drivers for a microcontroller) that is completely throwing off the language statistics. I have read [this page](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md) and I have created a `.gitattributes` file in my repository that should mark all these driver files as `linguist-vendored` and keep them from being included in the statistics. Although `git check-attr` reports the `linguist-vendored` attribute as being set, the `github-linguist` command line tool still ignores this. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ cat .gitattributes
STM32[[:space:]]Code/*/** linguist-vendored
STM32[[:space:]]Code/*/Core/Src/** -linguist-vendored
STM32[[:space:]]Code/*/Core/Inc/** -linguist-vendored

$ git add .gitattributes
$ git commit --amend --no-edit
[master 017861e] fix github language metrics
 Date: Sat Sep 25 16:09:00 2021 -0700
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes

$ git check-attr -a "STM32 Code/BLDC/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal.c"
STM32 Code/BLDC/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal.c: linguist-vendored: set

$ github-linguist --breakdown
94.75%  C
2.92%   C++
2.09%   Makefile
0.23%   Assembly
0.01%   Shell

...
C:
STM32 Code/BLDC/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal.c
...
```

I have also tried changing the `.gitattributes` file to just

```
STM32[[:space:]]Code/** linguist-vendored
```

and it still doesn't ignore the files inside.

Comment: Did you commit the changes?

Comment: @pchaigno Yes, I committed the changes to my local repository (using `git commit --amend --no-edit`), but haven't pushed them to GitHub yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you may be using an old version of Linguist and/or rugged (which is what does the checking of the gitattributes); possibly the versions shipped with your OS as I can't reproduce your behaviour using the latest version which GitHub is using:

```
$ gem install github-linguist
Fetching github-linguist-7.16.1.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed github-linguist-7.16.1
1 gem installed
$ git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/lildude/Downloads/trash/foo/.git/
$ mkdir -p "foo/STM32 Code/BLDC/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/"
$ echo "foo" > "foo/STM32 Code/BLDC/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal.c"
$ cd foo
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
$ github-linguist . --breakdown
100.00% 4          C

C:
STM32 Code/BLDC/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal.c

$ echo "STM32[[:space:]]Code/*/** linguist-vendored" > .gitattributes
$ git add .gitattributes
$ git commit -m 'overwrite'
[main 15e0a4e] overwrite
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
$ github-linguist . --breakdown


$
```

Comment: That was the problem! I was using Linguist (version 7.7.0) installed with the `apt` package manager shipped with Ubuntu 20.04. After uninstalling that package and reinstalling Linguist (version 7.16.1) with `gem`, it still didn't work even with copy and pasting the exact commands you used to test. Running `gem install rugged` (which got rugged version 1.2.0) then reinstalling Linguist fixed the problem (IDK if reinstalling Linguist was necessary). So, it seems like the version of rugged that's shipped with Ubuntu 20.04 is old. Thanks for the help!